# Elementor for wordpress website is stopped working on Project Page

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have used elementor for building my website page but when adding new project through wordpress and when editing it with elementor its giving error for that particualr page don't know why.
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjbp1.jpg)
Please help me to get out of it my work is pending cause of this.

Comment: Please refrain using images or screenshot of text, wherever possible paste the output or even write it as people tend to ignore questions with images attached without any good reason. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more help in asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once. In my case it had to do with a bad configuration in my theme. I was creating a new theme from start and I was (wrongly) using the `index.php` for my dynamic content. What I did was created the `front-page.php` and pasted here the content that were in my `index.php` and problem solved.

Also you must check if you are calling to `wp_footer()` in you footer.php template.
I hope this help you. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can occur generally due to low server configuration. Please make sure you have the following settings on your server:

```
max_execution_time = 600

upload_max_filesize = 32M

post_max_size = 48M

memory_limit = 600M

max_input_time = 300

max_input_vars = 10000
```

Hopefully, it helps you to solve your problem.